# Sublime Text 3 + Build (ctrl + b)

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have a problem with sublime text after upgrading to Ubuntu 20 from Linux Mint 19

My problem is, I have a python3.8 project, and my directory structure is (simplified)

```
a.py
tests/
  - b.py
```

and the file `b.py` might read

```
# b.py
import a
```

When running this code in the terminal, it works, but when running in the sublime text builder I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

So it is like sublime text doesn't know that the file in the directory above exists

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `import ..a` or `from .. import a`?

Comment: yeah, didn't work...also it should not be necessary, it still works on my old laptop, it's a matter of sublime text configuration